# How to handle clock skew in audio streaming

Tags: audio, gstreamer, audio-streaming, alsa, skew

Problem :

1. Its live audio-video streaming over WiFi + udp network.
2. Stream : Mpeg2Ts
3. Player Framework : gstreamer.
4. Pipeline  Appsrc ----> tsdemuxer -----> audio-queue---->faad decoder--->alsasink
                         -         ----->video-queue->vpudecoder ---->videosink
5. Audio device is configured for processing 48000 samples per second.
6. Senders clock is faster than receiver clock  and i get this info by tracking the pcr value coming in the stream and receiver system clock. After 1 hour there is 8 second difference between sender and receiver clocks.
7. So problem is sender is sending more samples in one seconds with respect to receiver clock due to this latency between sender and receiver is keep increasing with the time.

Answer (score 2):

The clock skew should be automatically handled by GStreamer's synchronization mechanisms and the skewing logic inside the audio sink base class.

To solve your problem of increasing latency between sender and receiver, you would have to timestamp the input properly instead of relying on the timestamps inside the TS stream (which are based on the sender clock and thus wrong on your side). For that it might already be enough to use a recent enough GStreamer version and setting do-timestamp=true and format=time on the appsrc.

Comment: I can't use latest version of gstreamer. Currently ,i am using gstreamer-0.10.36. In Demuxer (tsdemuxer) gstreamer has used an algorithm for handling the clock skew .Algorithm requires the receiving timestamp of rtp packets that contains pcr info. Using PCR (program clock refernce) values of sender and receiving value of the packet , it's calculating the difference between the sender's clock and receiver clock . Diff = (PCR-PACKET-RECV-TIME-N - PCR-PACKET-RECV-TIME-1) - (PCR-VALUE-N - PCR-VALUE-1).

Comment: Depending upon the diff , it's calculating the running average of skew and updating the PTS(presentation timestamp) of every packet for receiver's clock .Now according this logic video playback has no drift but audio playback is drifting over the time. So basically i am facing audio-video sync problem.

Comment: If this is RTP, why are you not just using an udpsrc and rtpbin? How do you get the RTP packets into your application?

To preserve A/V sync you need to make sure that audio and video that belongs together has the same running time.